# jquery selector drill-down?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have

```
$('.rotator li').each(function() {
  $(this).further-nested-elements.somefunction();
});
```

how can I reference elements that are nested below `this` so I don't have to keep re-typing the original selector (i.e. `$('.rotator li')`) every time I want to access it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find):

```
$(this).find(".someClass");
```

Or, use `this` as the [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#selector-context):

```
$(".someClass", this);
```

I prefer the second method because, in my head at least, it seems like it has to do less work - only one function call, creating only one jQuery object instead of two.

Comment: Works great, should've been more obvious to me in the first place. Thanks!

Comment: @gilly3, alas, `$("selector", element)` resolves internally to `$(element).find("selector")`, so your second code snippet will not be faster (see lines 189-193 in the [current source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js)).

Comment: @Frédéric - Ah, I was afraid of that.  So, in fact, it's a tiny bit slower since it means an extra function call and wading through all of those `if` statements, whereas `$(this)` is handled by the second `if` statement.  But, still, in my head it seems nicer... it might be tough to change my ways!  ☺

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use:

```
 $(this).children("further_selector")
```

or

```
 $(this).find("further_selector")
```